# How to not display file name of html5 input

Tags: html, css

I'm doing frontend work and I'd like to separate the two components of this file type input, I want 'Choose File' on one line and 'No File' chosen on another, or not display 'No file chosen' at all (incl after a file is selected for the input).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a simple trick to get the result using css to hide the input and view just a label

```
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> choose File
</label>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>

input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

here is a fiddle to see the result  [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/4cwpLvae/1242/)

Answer (score 0):

file input is element that comes with browse button and selected filename, you have no ability to change some of it parts because it is monolith. but you can hide whole filename element and show your own custom browse button.